# Phpmailer - add posted value in email body

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, email, phpmailer

I'm having a little problem with my contact form.
I'm using bootstrap and phpmailer.
The problem is that the email body doesn't include variables from contact form.

The massage i'm getting on my email is "Wiadomość od: Firma: E-mail: Telefon: Treść wiadomości:

The code is down below:

```
<?php



require '../../PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
// require '../../PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;                        
$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'xxx.com.pl';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
$mail->Username = 'xxx@.com.pl';                
$mail->Password = 'xxx';                         
$mail->Port = 587;


$mail->setFrom('xxx@.com.pl', 'Centru');
$mail->addAddress('xxx@gmail.com', 'Odbiorca');    
$mail->Subject = "Wiadomość ze strony internetowej";
$mail->isHTML(true);   


// $name = $_POST['InputName'];
// $company = $_POST['InputFirma'];
// $email = $_POST['InputEmail'];
// $phone = $_POST['InputPhone'];
// $message = $_POST['InputSubject']; 


$mail->Body = "Wiadomość od: " .$_POST['InputName']."\nFirma: " .$_POST['InputFirma']. "\nE-mail: " .$_POST['InputEmail']. "\nTelefon: " .$phone = $_POST['InputPhone']. "\nTreść wiadomości: " .$_POST['InputSubject'];

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Wiadomość nie mogła zostać wysłana';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Wiadomość została wysłana';
}
```

and HTML

```
<form class="padding-top-40" role="form" id="contactForm" class="contact-form" data-toggle="validator" class="shake">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="InputName">Imię i nazwisko</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputName" name="fullname"  placeholder="Imię i nazwisko" required data-error="Proszę wpisać swoje imię i nazwisko">
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="InputFirma">Firma</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFirma" name="subject" name="comments"  placeholder="Firma" required data-error="Proszę wpisać nazwę firmy">
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="InputEmail">E-mail</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" name="emailid"  placeholder="E-mail" required data-error="Proszę wpisać swój email">
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="InputPhone">Telefon kontaktowy</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="phone" id="InputPhone" placeholder="Numer telefonu" required data-error="Proszę wprowadzić numer telefonu">
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="InputSubject">Temat</label>
                            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" name="subject"  id="InputSubject" placeholder="Treść wiadomości" rows="4" required data-error="Proszę wpisać treść wiadomości"></textarea>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="padding-top-20">
                            <button type="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" >Wyślij</button>
                            <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Add `method="post"` to your <form>, I guess?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't change anything :/

Comment: You access wrong element, var_dump($_POST) and you will see. Imię i nazwisko has name="fullname" so it will be $_POST['fullname'] not $_POST['InputName'], InputName is an ID. Key for $_POST array is a NAME attribute.

edit: and ofcourse method="post" as @ChrisG mentioned.

Comment: Ok that one is working thank you. However i will refer to you as well to problem: " 
Well it kinda works, however it only catches 'phone' name which is weird. Oh and also "\n" doesn't seem to work (i assume it breaks the line right?) "

Comment: You can add `Content-Type: text/plain` to the email's header and `\n` should work. Or use `Content-Type: text/html` and `<br>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I've found a solution to my problem.

I've made an array instead of plain "body" script.
Hope it will help someone.

```
$mail->Body = join('', array(
"Wiadomość od: ",
$_POST['name'],
"<br/>",
"Firma: ",
$_POST['company'],
"<br/>",
"E-mail: ",
$_POST['email'],
"<br/>",
"Telefon:",
$_POST['phone'],
"<br/>",
"Treść wiadomości: ",
"<br/>",
$_POST['content']
));
```

Answer (score 0):

use name instead of id and check

```
   $name=$this->input->post('fullname');


   $name=$_POST['fullname'];
```

Comment: Well it kinda works, however it only catches 'phone' name which is weird. Oh and also "\n" doesn't seem to work (i assume it breaks the line right?)

Comment: use <br> and not \n

Comment: also remove id if u dont need and give just one name for each element....you have two name fields for firma

Comment: Did that. Now i get "undefined" string.

Comment: for all the values?

Comment: Nope - only for phone. For the rest i get nothing.

Comment: how are you sending the values..ajax or method="post" action="mail.php"??

Comment: I do have implemented Ajax, nad also gave <form> method="post" and action="mail.php"

Comment: use only one...if ajax then u need to pass the data  url: '',
        method: "POST",
        data: $.param({
                    data: data
                }), .....but incase of method="post" this should work